# How to make button redirecting to external link in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm newbie here. I am very need help from you to solve this problem, please.

I want to link the button name 'lihat rincian' and every row of tables to redirect to external link like http://website.com/

[My view of datatables Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ccS.jpg)

The view is datatables, and that button is on my controller. The function for link to other page before is 'detail' and for list for datatables is 'ajax_list2'. For information my database name is 'crud' and tables is 'edulib'

This is my controller. Controller name : edulibs

```html
/*for load */
public function detail()
 {
  $this->session->set_userdata('url',current_url());
  $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
  $data['detail']=$this->edulib_model->get_where('edulib','id',$id);
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->view('profil',$data);
  
 }

/* for list */
public function ajax_list2()
 {
  $list = $this->edulibs->get_datatables();
  $data = array();
  $no = $_POST['start'];
  foreach ($list as $edulibs) {
   $no++;
   $row = array();
   $row[] = $edulibs->nama;
   $row[] = $edulibs->pembimbing1;
   $row[] = $edulibs->pembimbing2;
   $row[] = $edulibs->subyek;
   $row[] = $edulibs->judul;
   $row[] = $edulibs->tanggal;

   //add html for action
   $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary center-block" href="'."detail/".$edulibs->id."".'" title="Tampilkan"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> Lihat Rincian</a>';
  
   $data[] = $row;
  }

  $output = array(
      "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
      "recordsTotal" => $this->edulibs->count_all(),
      "recordsFiltered" => $this->edulibs->count_filtered(),
      "data" => $data,
    );
  //output to json format
  echo json_encode($output);
 }
```

Thank you very much for your help before. I am very need your help
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that by external link you mean in a new tab you can just add a target attribute to your link, for a website link you can just change the href value, like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary center-block" href="http://website.com/" target="_blank" title="Tampilkan"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> Lihat Rincian</a>
```